# replace first occurrence of text using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

The code below replaces the first occurrence of apple with banana.
How do I achieve the same using awk / gawk?

```
sed -i "0,/apple/s//banana/" myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

this is what I come up with:

```
awk '!x{x=sub("apple","banana")}7' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  cat f
foo
apple
foo
apple
apple

kent$  awk '!x{x=sub("apple","banana")}7' f
foo
banana
foo
apple
apple
```

for the `sed -i` (change in place) part, if you use gawk 4.1.0, you have that option too. otherwise, you have to use a temp file.

Comment: you are using the `7`. That's funny! :) +1

Comment: @hek2mgl if I used `1`, you could `+1`, now I used `7`, you should `+7` :)  no special reason, I like that number..

Comment: never seen this before. but of course any number except of `0` is valid.. like `awk` so much!! but if you ask me `sed` is more appropriate here. (that's why I gave that answer)...

Comment: @hek2mgl No. try  `-1`

Comment: thx. was about about to try just in this moment :) ... yes, that's a useful information

Comment: @hek2mgl if there was only `-1`, like `awk '-1' file`, it could have problem.

Comment: @Kent I am using gawk for windows. I am seeing this error.gawk: fatal: `!x{x' is not a legal variable name. My one liner is gawk -v "!x{x=sub("apple","banana")}7" myfile.txt > tempfile.txt

Comment: No I meant just: `awk '-1' file` (It prints the usage information).... Btw, `on Windows` : I offer my condolence. Have installed a windows7 home network for friends the whole (last 3) days... grrrrrr.. ;)

Comment: @SantoshPillai I never tried awk in windows, don't know the difference. can you try `awk '{if(x==0)x=sub(/foo/,"bar")}7' file`

Comment: hey @SantoshPillai I just read your comment carefully, why you have a `-v` ? remove it and try.

Comment: @kent gawk: fatal: `{if(x' is not a legal variable name

Comment: @SantoshPillai did you remove the `-v` ?

Comment: yes, now i dont see any errors. but there are no replacements done :(

Comment: You just nerd-sniped me, but I managed to figure out what the hell that `7` was at the end. It's only a truey thing acting as a second instruction, which is an implicit `print $0`, isn't it? You bastards. I love it.

Comment: What is that 7 number? I tried some numbers, they all worked except 0. Would you explain the whole command with details please?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin because non-zero number does default action in awk: print

Comment: So what is the difference between using 7, 777 or -1?. Actually I still new to AWK, would you recommend any reference which explain the syntax you wrote? I tried yesterday to find something helpful with no success. Or maybe any keyword to search for? (except `AWK` keyword ;))

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin no difference. I prefer right index finger, so I picked 7

Comment: OK to help the others, another form of the command to make it more readable: `awk '!x{x=sub("apple","banana")}{print $0}' test`. substituting {print} with a number (any thing other than 0 is true), makes {print} to be true (even is not written). This syntax `!x{...}` means: if x != false (i.e. if it has a value) do something. The rest should be clear for any essential knowledge programmer.